# Can the directories wiped by mvn clean be customized?

Tags: maven, maven-clean-plugin

After running

```
mvn clean
```

I had kind of a bad moment when trying to run a binary in my project. First the selected binary did not run - then discovered the *entire /bin directory had been removed*.  After a bit of a panic it came out that - among the durable/checked in files - *only* the bin directory had been nuked.

Here is a snippet of the results of the `mvn clean` : while the `libs` dir is desirable to remove .. the `bin` *is not*.

```
--- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ parent ---
[INFO] Deleting /git/OCspark/bin (includes = [], excludes = [])
[INFO] Deleting /git/OCspark/libs (includes = [**/*.jar], excludes = [])
```

Is there a configuration to inform clean what is "OK" to wipe and what is "off limits" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure the maven-clean-plugin to [include and exclude](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/examples/delete_additional_files.html) the additional files. Check for any existing inclusions and exclusions.

Alternatively, you can try to use two `fileset`s in the configuration for include and exclude separately, somewhat like(not tested) :

```
<configuration>
  <filesets>
    <fileset>
      <directory>/git/OCspark/libs</directory>
      <includes>
        <include>**/*.*</include>
      </includes>
      <followSymlinks>false</followSymlinks>
    </fileset>
    <fileset>
      <directory>/git/OCspark/bin</directory>
      <excludes>
        <exclude>**/*.*</exclude>
      </excludes>
      <followSymlinks>false</followSymlinks>
    </fileset>
  </filesets>
</configuration>
```

Comment: oh man! I had an explicit `include` for deleting `bin`!  One can see this project has been around a while